# Tortoise Git — как вернуть пункт Show Log в контекстное меню Windows 10?

Tags: git, tortoise-git

В контекстном меню нет пункта Show Log. 
В настройках он включен. 
Но появляется только при зажатом Shift. В чем может быть причина? Как можно исправить?

В настройках выставлено
[image: 5b04341eb7478892579055.png]
и
[image: 5b04342b6e45d121399135.png]

Вид контекстного меню без зажатого Shift:
[image: 5b04343e1a617006256632.png]

**Какие могут быть решения?**

Используется:
TortoiseGit 2.6.0.0 
git version 2.16.2.windows.1 
Windows 10

Comment: Поубирать пробелы и другие специальные символы из имён папок, в которых хранится проект. Windows до сих пор не умеет работать с файлами и папками, в именах которых пробельные символы.

Comment: Попробовал развернуть проект на "D:\React-projects\_template-react", увы, это решение не сработало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас стоит галочка на `Show Log` в `Set Extend Menu Item`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст над списком: `Don't show the selected items: (press shift key to show them)` подсказывает, что отмеченные в этом списке пункты меню появляются только при зажатом шифте.
Соответственно чтобы работало без шифта просто снимаете галочку (оставив её только в списке `Context Menu`).

Comment: Попробовал снять галочку в этом списке. К сожалению это решение не помогло. Попробовал скрыть какой-то из существующих пунктнов в списке Context Menu через Set Extend Menu. Это тоже не сработало. Что-то еще от меня может помочь вам с вариантами решения?

Comment: @Skif Проверил у себя - работает как задумано, но не всегда сразу, закономерности не уловил, возможно требуется перезапуск проводника.

Comment: Порядок. Да, оказалось именно для этого пункта нужна обязательная перезагрузка. Большинство остальных срабатывают сразу. Спасибо.